# How do I correctly implement this switch statement?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, return

I'm new to Javascript and I cannot get my switch statement to work correctly with each function or my default. Every thing I have tried fixes one issue but creates another. How do I correctly use my switch statement to get the correct return for my cases.

```js
const f_to_c = (f = 32) => {
  total = 5 / 9 * (f - 32)
  result = (f + 'F = ' + total + 'C')
  return result;
}
console.log(f_to_c());

const c_to_f = (y = 0) => {
  total = 9 / 5 * (y) + 32
  results = (y + 'C = ' + total + 'F')
  return results;
}
console.log(c_to_f())

const convertTemp = (x = 'str', int = 0) => {

  switch ('f', 'c') {
    case 'c':
      return c_to_f(int);
    case 'f':
      return f_to_c(int);
    default:
      return ('Not an accurate temperature degree type..')
  }
};
console.log(convertTemp())
```

Comment: What's wrong exactly, what's the "not correct" output, and what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: `('f', 'c')` what is that meant to mean?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a bit more how to create switch statement, here is good [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```js
const convertTemp = (x = 'c', int = 0) => {  
    switch(x){
        case 'c':
             return c_to_f(int);
        case 'f':
            return f_to_c(int); 
        default:
            return ('Not an accurate temperature degree type..')
    }
};
```